# Login na conta do usuário dentro da pagina Index

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou a desenvolver um sistema onde todos os funcionários podem entrar na página Index.php (Página de trabalho), de modo geral onde todos eles conhecem o codigo e a senha e entra normalmente no sistema (Sem restrições e nesse caso para quem chegar primeiro no trabalho:)), só quê quando um entra mostra todos funcionários.

Portanto eu quero que quando um deles quiser alterar os seu dados, ou ver a sua página, ela é direcionada na sua página e ao sair volta para a página index.php que já estava logado sem ter que sair dela e depois logar novamente.

Para isto queria pedir somente a senha do funcionário através da janela modal para ser redirecionado a página dele. Alguém pode me ajudar nisso por favor?

Comment: A pergunta está um pouco confusa. `Portanto eu quero quando um deles quiser alterar os seu dados ou ver a sua página ela é direcionada na sua página e ao sair, volta para a página index.php que já estava logado sem ter que sair dela e depois logar novamente.` Esse um deles, provavelmente, é o primeiro a chegar no trabalho e logar, correto?  Explica isso melhor `sem ter que sair dela`, abre a pagina dele na mesma janela?

Comment: Desculpem a confusão. O que eu quero dizer é: Temos a página principal onde todos funcionários têm acesso (a senha)  e nesta pagina está listado todos os funcionários. Só que quando um dos funcionário quiser acessar a sua página, clicar no botão k abre um modal onde irá colocar a sua senha ao clicar no botão "logar" deve redirecionar na página dele. Agora quando ele quiser sair da página dele volta na página principal onde todo mundo tem acesso sem ter que logar novamente. EM OUTRAS PALAVRAS: A pág do funcionário deve estar dentro da pág principal p/ quando sair pemanencer na página principal.

Comment: Poderia abrir a pagina do funcionário em nova aba ou janela, assim a pagina principal estaria aberta na outra aba. Agora,  `A pág do funcionário deve estar dentro da pág principal`está me cheirando ser um modal no qual ele pode ver e editar seus dados.

Comment: Então pode ser da seguinte maneira: Quando clica no botão abre o modal, coloca a senha e abre uma nova aba na conta do funcionario

Comment: Se as respostas as suas perguntas resolverem o problema marque-as como aceitas. Veja como e porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: Vi em uma pergunta sua, no comentário da resposta `Foi resolvido sim! Valdeir Psr, muito obrigado. Mas nao tenho ideia onde marcar que esta resolvido, tem algum sitio para marcar caso tenha resolvido aqui no StackOverflow` . Para marcar uma resposta como aceita, clique na marca de verificação do lado esquerdo da resposta; sua cor mudará de cinza para verde.  Veja https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhKaX.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Editada 12/04/2018 10:36

Segundo comentário do AP

<sub>Então pode ser da seguinte maneira: Quando clica no botão abre o modal, coloca a senha e abre uma nova aba na conta do funcionario</sub>

> Caso seja isso que você quer, depois posto a explicação do código.

[**Exemplo funcionando**](http://kithomepage.com/sos/login-com-modal-usuarios.php)

**Pagina index**

```
<?php
session_start();

$connect = new mysqli ("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "NOME_DB");

$textoLabel="Digite sua senha";

if (isset($_POST["senha"]) && $_POST["senha"]!="") { 
    $senha = $_POST["senha"];
    $id = $_POST["campoOculto"];

    $sql="select * from nomeTabela where senha='$senha' && id='$id'";

    $buscar=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    $result=mysqli_num_rows($buscar);

    if ($result==1) {
        $dados=mysqli_fetch_array($buscar);
        $_SESSION["usuario"]=$dados["nome"];
        echo '<script>window.open("usuarios/usuario.php");</script>'; 
    }else{
        $textoLabel = "Senha inválida";
        $modal="mostrar";
    }

}
if (isset($_POST["senha"]) && $_POST["senha"]=="") {
    $textoLabel = "Você deve digitar sua senha";
    $modal="mostrar";
}

?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
function setaDadosModal(valor) {
    document.getElementById('campoOculto').value = valor;
}
</script>

<?php
if ($modal=="mostrar"){
?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>

<?php
}

    $sql2="select * from nomeTabela";
    $listar=mysqli_query($connect,$sql2);

    $tabela .= '<div style="float: center" table align="center">';

    $tabela .= '<table border="1">';

    $tabela .= '<tr>';

    $tabela .='<thead>';

    $tabela .= '<tr>';

    $tabela .= '<th>nome</th>';

    $tabela .='</thead>'; 

    $tabela .='<tbody>';

    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($listar)) {

        $tabela .= '<tr>';

        $tabela .= '<td><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="setaDadosModal(\''.$rows['id'].'\')">'.$rows['nome'].'</a></td>';

        //$tabela .= '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="setaDadosModal(\''.$rows['id'].'\')">'.$rows['nome'].'</button></td>';

    }

    $tabela .= '</tr>';

    $tabela .='</tbody>'; 

    $tabela .= '</table>';

    $tabela .= '</div>';

    echo $tabela;

    mysqli_close($connect); 
?>


<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Login </h4>
        </div>
        <form id="mudarsenha" method="post" name="form_mudar_senha" action="" autocomplete="off">
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="md-form ml-0 mr-0">
                <input name="senha" type="password">
                <input type="hidden" name="campoOculto" id="campoOculto">
                <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" class="ml-0"><?php echo $textoLabel ?></label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-rounded waves-effect waves-light" ><span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-send"></i></span> Enviar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**usuario.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$connect = new mysqli ("localhost", "USUARIO", "SENHA", "NOME_DB");

echo "Pagina do usuario ".$_SESSION["usuario"];

$nome = $_SESSION["usuario"];

$sql="select * from nomeTabela where nome='$nome'";

    $listar=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);

    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($listar)) {

      ........
      ........

    }

    mysqli_close($connect); 
?>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Leonardo pela disposição e paciência. Usei o seu codigo com algumas alterações más está tudo a funcionar bem. Eu agradeço muito.